# Using Postgis,The shell prompt Invalid endian flag value encountered,when I want to do MBR to my WKB_geometry

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to calculate the MBR for the column of table.

I have already install Postgis and postgresql.

the data is cvs
[image]

and I load the data to my postgresql-table by [copy]

and my table scheme is
[image]

and When I running

> SELECT ST_Envelope (wkb_geometry::geometry) from test1;

OR
running

> SELECT PostGIS_ADDBBox(wek_geometry) from test1;

the shell prompt me

> ERROR:Invalid endian flag value encountered.

**I just want to create the Minimum bounding box（MBR） to my table(by postgis,and using web_geometry column),but I don't know what should I using the function and what the correct syntax**

Answer (score 1):

If i read it correct you import a WKT and then you try to cast wkb_geometry to geometry. You picture shows a text file with WKT and fields of your table called wkb_geometry. How do you imported the data? Either you have a real binary field where you threw in text or your field has a different name compared to its content.

WKT and WKB are completly different things, you can´t mix them. One is stored as text the other as binary format. Therefore different tools are needed. I don´t think that the normal cast function will work here anyway, as this is a postgresql standard function and has nothing to do with geometries, you need the PostGIS functions. If you really have a WKB you need the function ST_GeomFromWKB.

```
Select ST_Envelope(StGeomfromWKB(your field, your coordinate reference as srid))
```

Or for WKT you go with STGeomFromText:

```
SELECT ST_Envelope(STGeomFromText(your field, your coordinate reference as srid))
```

Comment: I load the data by ogr2ogr（.shp -----> .csv ） and when I running `Select ST_Envelope(St_GeomFromWKB(wkb_geometry, 4326)) from test1;` The prompt： `ERROR: Invalid endian flag value encountered`. and when I running： `SELECT wkb_geometry From test1 where fnode_=1; `the web_geometry is `\x4c494e45535452494e4720283132312e32393636373932373136333234‌​39392033312e38353239‌​34383130313631323438‌​2c3132312e3239353838‌​333137383731 > 3039382033312e38343933353536393736333137393729`

Comment: and when I running：` Select ST_GeomFromText(wkb_geometry,0) from test1;`   the prompt `> ERROR: function st_geomfromtext(bytea, integer) does not exist LINE > 1: Select ST_GeomFromText(wkb_geometry,0) from test1; > ^ HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. `    I have already don't know what the wkb_geometry format –

Comment: How did you bring the .csv into the database? Because it has WKT as geometry format and your column wkb. I guess that the error lies there. When you import the csv you need to have the same columns. Lets test the following: Create a new table with all columns named like the ones in your .csv file. The WKT-Column as text. Then COPY new_table FROM "file" . The copy command needs the same amount of columns in the input and output table. Try your query with the new table.

Comment: yep，I know use COPY should have same column，  first I using ogr2ogr load the table（new table,named test），and I go to 【pgAdmin】to see the SQL of the table scheme. And I create new table（named test1） column and create column the same as the test. So I think the table(test1) have the same  column .(Because the next step I want to using cities,so I must create new table)

Comment: I already  run `CREATE table test2(
WKT text,fnode_ integer,tnode_ integer,lpoly_ integer,rpoly_ integer,length double precision,riverf_ integer,riverf_id integer,code integer,gb integer,hydc text,tn integer,name text);`    and  `COPY test2 FROM '/home/pj/Desktop/test1.csv' CSV header;`  but prompt error: `ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY test2, line 2: ""LINESTRING (121.28987121582 31.852741241455099,121.286529541015994 31.8526306152344,121.28036499023..."`

Comment: I load the data directly  to new table by `ogr2ogr` ，and when I running `Select ST_Envelope(St_GeomFromWKB(wkb_geometry, '4326')) from test_1 where ogc_fid=1;`   it show `WARNING:  OGC WKB expected, EWKB provided - use GeometryFromEWKB() for this    st_envelope                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 010300……(1 row)` so I guess the Before error is because of load data  ，but why have the warning?

Comment: but I don't know  if I calculate the MBR，what should I do to add the result to the table？

Comment: Usually you would not add it to this table as it is a new geometry. When you have your select-statement in order just create a new table or view with it. That you can use to visualize or use it for other tasks (e.g. calculating the area).

Comment: I want to according to this result to calculate the Hilbert value，so I want to added this result to the table or have any others idea to connect the ogc_fid  and the MBR ？